# Dividir em blocos os resultados do mysql

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema do qual cadastra a quantidade de pessoas em um determinado estabelecimento que vai de 1 a 200 e cada estabelecimento comporta até 3 pessoas. Como eu faria para que ao trazer do mysql essa quantidade, fossem divididas em blocos. Por ex.:

**Como estou trazendo atualmente**

```
<?php
....
$c = 1;
while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMostrar)){
   $mostrar .= "Estabelecimento " . $c . "<br>";
   $mostrar .= $jm->Nome. " " .$jm->Idade;
 $c++; 
}
```

Dessa forma ele traz corrido e não em blocos. Gostaria que trouxesse esse resultado da seguinte forma. Vamos supor que o cliente cadastrou 09 pessoas:

```
**Estabelecimento 1**
Fernando Pessoa 32 anos
Ruth Cardoso 56 anos
Santos Dumont 60 anos

**Estabelecimento 2**
Carlos Drummond de Andrade 70 anos
Mario Lago 72 anos
Manuel Bandeira 60 anos

**Estabelecimento 3**
Olavo Bilac 22 anos
Cecília Meireles 25 anos
Gonçalves Dias 55 anos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se para seu caso isso seria vantajoso por conta da perfomance, mas o que poderia ser feito é dividir o resultado através da função `array_chunk`. Para isso teríamos que utilizar `Mysqli::fetch_all`, ao invés de `fetch`.

```
$chunks = array_chunk(mysqli_fetch_all($sql), 3)
```

E depois:

```
<?php foreach ($chunks as $key => $results) : ?>
   Estabelecimento <?= $key+1?>
   <?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
      ...
   <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Outra solução é verificar num loop se o número é divisível por três, para poder gerar esse "pulo de 3 em três".

Exemplo:

```
$c = 1;
$d = 0;
while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMostrar)){

   if ($d++ % 3 == 0) {
      $mostrar .= "Estabelecimento " . $c . "<br>";
      $c++;
   }

   $mostrar .= $jm->Nome. " " .$jm->Idade;
}
```

Comment: Oi Wallace, usei seu código, porém dá o erro Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all(). A versão do php é 5.5.29. Será que está havendo alguma incompatibilidade?

Comment: Oi Wallace. Infelizmente esse seu último exemplo também nao funcionou. Não aparece o resultado após a condicional if().

Comment: Para a primeira pergunta: Sim, o erro ocorre porque você está usando uma versão inferior a 5.3 do PHP.

Comment: Para a segunda pergunta: Usei seu código de exemplo. Verifique se você iniciou a variável `$mostrar` antes do loop.

Comment: Tem um erro no código :\ O `$d` tem que ser `0`

Comment: Coloquei o  $contar = $jmListar->QtdPax;
         
        for($cc = 0; $cc < $contar; $cc++) e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida para fechar. Vamos supor que os blocos sejam divididos em 2 e no banco traga 5, automaticamente o último campo constará só um. Como eu faria para que mesmo com a diferença, ele feche com 02 blocos?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não compreendi bem, mais vou supor que o cadastro de pessoas é sequencial, e você simplesmente esta distribuindo as pessoa.
Tambem não foi definido que a quebra é vertical ou horizontal.

```
# SIMULA AS PESSOA
$pessoa = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++){ 
    $pessoa[] = array(
        'nome' => "Pessoa {$i}",
    );
}

# CRIA ARRAY HIPOTIPÓTICO
$estabelecimento = array();
$estabelecimento2 = array();
$x = 0;
foreach ($pessoa as $k => $options){
    # QUEBRA HORIZONTAL
    $estabelecimento[$k%3][] = $options;

    # QUEBRA VERTIVAL
    if($k%3 == 0){
        $estabelecimento2[++$x][] = $options;
    }else{
        $estabelecimento2[$x][] = $options;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($estabelecimento);
print_r($estabelecimento2);
```